# Connection refused - Could not fetch user details - when trying to access the Authentication Server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-security

I want to point my Organization service to the Authentication server.

When I am trying to call the following request:
GET http://localhost:8082/v1/organizations/{{organizationId}}

I am receiving the following WARNING

```
o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException, I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8901/auth/user": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

And I am also receiving the following response in POSTMAN

{
"error": "invalid_token",
"error_description": "6afd2822-b23d-4421-9902-423f0934d385"
}

However, when I am accesing GET http://localhost:8901/auth/user directly through Postman, without accesing it via my Organization service, the request works fine.

I am using Spring Cloud Hoxton SR11

**My Authentication server has the following configuration:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer 
public class AuthenticationServiceApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationServiceApplication.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/user" }, produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String, Object> user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
        LOGGER.debug("Request to get user info");
        Map<String, Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("user", user.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        userInfo.put("authorities", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(user.getUserAuthentication().getAuthorities()));
        return userInfo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthenticationServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /auth
```

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("eagleeye")
                .secret("{noop}thisissecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("john.carnell").password("{noop}password1").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("william.woodward").password("{noop}password2").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

**My Organization service has the following configuration**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@RefreshScope
@EnableResourceServer 
public class OrganizationServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrganizationServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/v1/organizations/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/


security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8901/auth/user
```

Thank you!